# How to position CSS circle/div top right of button without adding to button width?

Tags: html, css

I've got buttons with badge counters top right. The problem is the button width is expanding to cater for the width of the div (circle) if I put the div tag inside the button tag, and I don't want it to. I'd like the button width to be as it normally would if the circle div wasn't there. If I place the circle div outside the button tag, it obviously acts completely separately to the button and wraps to the next line.
(If it's relevant the buttons are centered in a table cell and there can be up to 5 of them in one cell.

[image]

I can get it looking right if I set the button to a fixed width and then use position: relative on the circle div and set the top and right px. But fixed width is no good because the buttons have variable content and so variable width.

What I really need is something like CSS: `width: calc(current_button_width - 16px);` but believe this is not possible?

Result wanted (faked using fixed-width buttons):

[image]

HTML (yes `&nbsp;` for button spacing will go!):

```
<td>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" style="width: 42px;">4 am
      <div class="numcircle">4</div>
   </button>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" style="width: 47px;">12 pm
      <div class="numcircle">1</div>
   </button>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
```

CSS for circle div (buttons are Twitter Bootstrap):

```
.numcircle {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    right: -1px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: tahoma, arial, 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Don't use position *relative* use `absolute` (with the button as `relativ`e) then the button will ignore the size of the circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `position:relative` on the circle use `absolute` (with the button as relative) then the button will ignore the size of the circle.

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2em;
}

.numcircle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: tahoma, arial, 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">12 pm
      <div class="numcircle">1</div>
   </button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Lorem, ipsum.
      <div class="numcircle">1</div>
   </button>
```